# .htaccess - redirect, if a specific url match

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect users to a new domain, but I need that in case a user visits a particular URL, then he/she needs to be redirected to another URL.

Let me clarify...

If the user visits `http://oldexample.com/postvendita/` I need to redirect them to `http://newexample.com/assistenza`

Otherwise, for every other URL `http://oldexample.com/*` I need to redirect them to `http://newexample.com/new-page`

Here is my attempt:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)postvendita(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/assistenza [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^oldexample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newexample.com/new-page [R=301,L]
```

Now if I visit **any** of the old pages, I will be redirected to `http://www.newexample.com/new-page`, so the first rule doesn't work, how should I change it?

Comment: Should we assume that you serve both domains from the same http server?

Comment: You are rewriting the _current_ request here, not anything where "the user comes from."

Comment: @CBroe That is not really true. The domain name `oldexample.com` can be viewed as such thing.

Comment: users coms from the old url clicking it on google or elsewhere

Comment: @arkascha yes, both site are on the same server right now

Comment: Then they are not "coming from" that URL (that usually refers to the page where they clicked a link, so the referrer), they simply request that URL.

Comment: @CBroe I guess we agree that "usually" does not really help when trying to understand a question, don't we?

Comment: Ok, sorry my bad with the definition. They click on a url

Comment: @arkascha and that is _why_ I am pointing out that the phrasing is abiguous.

Comment: The first rule _does_ work. The problem (assuming that both use the same .htaccess?) is that after the first rewrite, when the client requests `http://www.newexample.com/assistenza`, you redirect that _again_, because the host name is not `oldexample.com`. You want to add a check for whether it is not already `www.newexample.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle this via [.htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) you'll want to match the first one and use a catch-all to redirect everything else:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^postvendita/?$ http://www.newexample.com/assistenza [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule .*              http://www.newexample.com/new-page   [R=301,L,NE]
```

> A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which passes between 90-99% of
>   link juice (ranking power) to the redirected page. 301 refers to the
>   HTTP status code for this type of redirect. In most instances, the 301
>   redirect is the best method for implementing redirects on a website.

[More About Redirects](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)

Alternatively, if you're not comfortable writing RewriteRules, you can use the following lines:

```
Redirect 301 /postvendita/ http://www.newexample.com/assistenza
Redirect 301 /postvendita  http://www.newexample.com/assistenza
Redirect 301 /             http://www.newexample.com/new-page
```

Or with [RedirectMatch](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch/):

```
RedirectMatch 301 /postvendita/? http://www.newexample.com/assistenza
RedirectMatch 301 .*             http://www.newexample.com/new-page
```

[Common .htaccess Redirects](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489)